# Utility functions that a Symfony entity should have

Tags: php, symfony, orm

I don't know maybe it is me or may be it is symfony that is lame, please why is symfony entity class not having utility functions like these:

```
//Assume product is an entity class
$product = Product::findById($id);
$productExample = new Product(array("price"=>20, "vendor"=>'friends'));
$products = Product::findByExample($productExample);

$Dql = "SELECT * FROM product p WHERE p.id IN (SELECT si.pid FROM solditem si WHERE si.sold_date BETWEEN 1-1-2017 AND 2-2-2017 ORDER BY si.price)";
$products = Product::findByDql($Dql) or Product::findBySql($sql);

$product = new Product(array('id' => $id)); // I should be able to get the entity with that Id
```

In other frameworks like Zend (even small and simple ones like cakePHP, codeIgniter) it is very easy to implement functions like these and they will be callable everywhere, you will not have to be running after one entityManagers or entityCEOs.

Is there an easy way to implement way to implement these in symfony, if there is please let me know, if not please give me why.

Thanks

Comment: Well ... let's see. Active record constitutes a violation of single responsibility principle. And to add insult to injury - you also want to use static methods. Maybe you should stick with Cake or CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 4):

In general I suggest you read a little bit more about the documentations of the frameworks you are comparing.

> I don't know maybe it is me or may be it is symfony that is lame, please why is symfony entity class not having utility functions like these

To be honest in this case it is you ;-) ... no offense, but the systems are implementing different storage layers. Other frameworks like CodeIgniter, CakePHP and Laravel are implementing the [Active Record Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern). The latter e.g. by providing the [Eloquent ORM](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent)

> The Eloquent ORM included with Laravel provides a beautiful, simple ActiveRecord implementation for working with your database. Each database table has a corresponding "Model" which is used to interact with that table.

Symfony on the other hand is using [Doctrine 2 ORM](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/) as storage layer:

> As the term ORM already hints at, Doctrine 2 aims to simplify the translation between database rows and the PHP object model. The primary use case for Doctrine are therefore applications that utilize the Object-Oriented Programming Paradigm. For applications that do not primarily work with objects Doctrine 2 is not suited very well.

You can make up your own mind which one you favour, but it is not an easy task to swap the storage layer in these frameworks. If you search for it I think you will find some [discussions around this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3756014/is-there-a-way-of-using-php-activerecord-as-symfonys-orm-abstraction-layer).

In Symfony `Entity Repositories` are usually the [place](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#fetching-objects-from-the-database) where you define your desired functionality:

> When you query for a particular type of object, you always use what's
>   known as its "repository". You can think of a repository as a PHP
>   class whose only job is to help you fetch entities of a certain class.

Create a custom repository class following [the official documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/repository.html) or take it a step further and set up your own repository class without using Doctrines `EntityRepository` as [described in this highly recommended article](http://wouterj.nl/2016/12/repositories-are-just-collections/).

There is no one preventing you from adding static functions to it, but the recommended way is to make a service out of your repository, e.g.

**Repository**

```
// src/AppBundle/Product/DoctrineBasedProductRepository.php
namespace AppBundle\Product;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class DoctrineBasedProductRepository implements ProductRepository
{
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function all()
    {
        // Create a basic DQL query to fetch all entities
        return $this->entityManager->createQuery('SELECT p FROM '.Product::class.' p')
            ->getResult();
    }

   ...
}
```

**Service definition**

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    app.product_repository:
        class: AppBundle\Product\DoctrineBasedProductRepository
        arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']
```

Now you can use the repository e.g. in your controller:

```
public function listAction()
{
    $products = $this->get'app.product_repository')->all();


    // ... do something, like pass the $products object into a template
}
```

Comment: The act of writing some YAML config does not turn a repository into a service. Also, I would strongly advise not to use the Symfony's DIC component as a "service locator".

Comment: @tereško can you elaborate on your comment and what you would suggest?

Comment: @lordrhodos you usaly define the repository like so in the entity: `/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Namespace\Model\Repository\ProductRepository")
**/`

Comment: @Rufinus yes, I know that, but that alone will not make the repository itself available via the service container. You always need to inject / fetch it via the entity manager. So I am curious what tereško had in mind, to
 learn further about this topic ;-)

Comment: @lordrhodos what I was talking about is that both [services](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html) and [repositories](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) are concepts, that are completely unrelated to Symfony and their responsibilities are not affected by what you write in some configuration file. And as for "what is service locator and why it is bad": you will have t read about it your self, since it would require a lot more than a comment to explain it.

Comment: @lordrhodos I agree that I am the one that is very lame but I won't agree symfony doesn't have shortcoming infact many shortcomings, that may be the one that will later bow it to earth...

Comment: @AkinsNazri I am with you on the shortcomings side, there is no perfect framework out there covering all use cases. It is always a compromise.